# Does size of shared memory change during execution?

Tags: c++, shared-memory, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

My shared memory, implemented in C++, has a linked list. While I am adding elements to linked list, does its size change automatically ( as if it was an ordinary heap allocated element ) or it should contain only fixed size structures like a fixed size array ?

Comment: Do you know how linkedlists work? When a new element is added, it is just added dynamically, and a pointer will point to it from a previous data element. That should answer your question, yeah? If not, could you please elaborate what the real question is?

Comment: You should read my question more carefully. I do know very well how linked lists work. In normal life, we create linked list on the heap with dynamic memory allocation. However in my question I have stated that I have a Linked list created in shared memory area and as you might guess shared memory region has a fixed size which is different than heap. So I am asking that is it possible to initialize shared memory region such that when we add new insertions, its initial size will not be a problem. I mean it will behave like the heap. But I don t think this is possible.

Comment: Well, of course it is fixed size. Otherwise, you will need to create another bigger one if you cannot do big enough in advance.

Comment: So please read more carefully before you attempt to answer questions my friend.

Comment: I carefully read your stuff which I personally think is a bit sloppy, and somewhat self-evident. That is why I asked for clarification.

Comment: That is also why I did directly ignore your unrelated answers.

Comment: Good, so I hope you are happier now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In known operating systems such as Windows or Linux, the size of shared memory is fixed size and can not grow. You should create it big enough as you need. The only way in my opinion is to create another shared memory and copy data to it.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is as I guess unfortunately.